# Can I show both label and value on a pie chart label in MSChart

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart, data-visualization

I have a chart of type Doughnut from the Microsoft Chart Controls (in namespace System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting).

The data I'm binding to my chart's series is of type `Dictionary<string, int>` where the label is the key of the dictionary, and the value is the `Value` property.  I want my labels on the pie chart to look like this: `Some label (4)`, where "Some label" is the key of an entry in the dictionary, and 4 is the value.

I've tried various combinations of `IsValueShownAsLabel` and `LabelFormat`, but this doesn't help as it shows only the value.

I've come up with the following code which does what i want but, quite frankly, the last three lines (which set the labels) scare me!

```
Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary = GetMyDataForTheChart();
var mySeries = Chart1.Series.Add("MySeries");
mySeries.Points.DataBind(myDictionary, "Key", "Value", null);
int i = 0;
foreach (var p in mySeries.Points)
    p.Label = myDictionary.ElementAt(i++).Key + " (" + p.YValues[0].ToString("0") + ")";
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: >>Is there a better way?  I doubt it.

Comment: Did you try setting Label as `#VALX #VALY`, i think this should do the trick

Comment: @V4Vendetta Thanks very much for this, perfect! Please post this as an answer in order that I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to display the x and y values you can set the `Label=＃VALX ＃VALY` depending on the number of values bound you can also choose to extend it like `#VALY1` `#VALY2`and so on